# I want to convert html image tag into an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make this `html` tag an object.
This is the `html` tag:

```
<image id="v-182" width="50" height="50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="img/Email.png" title="Send Email" onclick="message()"></image>
```

Comment: `<image` is this your custom tag?

Answer (score 0):

That's some pretty basic Javascript :

```
var myImageTag = document.getElementById('v-182');
```

Or if you need it in your `message()` function, you can call it like that :

```
onclick="message(event)"
```

and get your tag into your function :

```
function message(event) {
var myImageTag = event.target;
}
```